# Attempting to store the results of a for loop into a var so the for loop redefines the contents of the file itself - java

Tags: java, reverse

So the purpose of this exercise was to read a file backwards and print it out.

I have achieve this but one other requirement is that when the method reverse() is called again, the file is reversed back. Now, since I had not actually  reversed the contents of the file, but only read it backwards, the code failed there.

What I then attempted to do was store the results of the backwards for loop into a variable(f) and then make the contents = f, so the text file would become the result of the for loop.

Maybe I should be using a filewriter to do this? or can it be done with the idea I had? I'm a java beginner so maybe its infeasible?

This code currently throws a "error variable f might have not been initialized"

Any suggestions on how to tackle the problem ? Thanks!

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FileIOReverse {

    public String contents = "";
    public String fileName;

    public FileIOReverse(String x) {
        fileName =  x;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String oneLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            //calls the method to read a using bufferedReader

            while(oneLine!=null){
                contents = contents + oneLine;
                oneLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

            //  Must follow this order: 1)Close the BufferedReader 2) Close the FileReader

            bufferedReader.close();
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occured");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    public String reverse(String contents){
        char f; 
        String ef;  
        for(int m = contents.length()-1; m >= 0; m--){
            f = contents.charAt(m); 
            //store the for loop result into a var for reuse
            System.out.print(f);
            ef = Character.toString(f);
            contents = ef;
        }    
        return contents;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FileIOReverse c = new FileIOReverse(args[0]);
        c.reverse(args[0]);      
        //returns an index out of bounds exception 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're just printing the reversed content, not storing it anywhere. Obviously, if you can't reverse something you don't have twice. Make `f` a String and accumulate the reversed content in it and at the end of the loop, replace `contents` with `f`, as you are now. Return `contents` from `reverse`. That way you can call reverse repeatedly and it will return the reversed content each time

Comment: thanks @pvg .I have done this, but the call returns an index out of bounds: 
     public String reverse(String contents){
        char f; 
        String ef;  
     for(int m = contents.length()-1; m >= 0; m--){
            f = contents.charAt(m); 
            //store the for loop result into a var for reuse
            System.out.print(f);
            ef = Character.toString(f);
            contents = ef;
        }    return contents;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        FileIOReverse c = new FileIOReverse(args[0]);
        c.reverse(args[0]);        
        }

}

Comment: That doesn't look quite right and it's impossible to read. Just update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a wee bit differently Mel. I would modify the reverse() method so that it is all it does but it also accepts an additional string ArrayList parameter. This way you can store Normal and reversed file text into separate lists.

The file would only need to be read once and at that point the text is reversed and filled into an ArrayList named **revText** then iterate through the ArrayList to display the reversed contents. The to reverse it all back to normal again you just need to iterate through the **revText** ArrayList yet again and supply yet another ArrayList variable named **normalText** to the reverse() method. Now iterate though the **normalText** ArrayList to display the normal text again.

Hmmmm...the more I type the more confusing this gets...here's the code :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileIOReverse{
    static String contents = "";
    static String fileName;
    static ArrayList<String> revText = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please supply the text file name to reverse\n"
                + "or enter nothing to quit: ->");
        fileName = in.nextLine();
        if ("".equals(fileName)) { System.exit(0); }

        FileIOReverse c = new FileIOReverse(fileName);

        System.out.println("Below is the reversed text:\n"
                         + "*************************************");
        for (int i = 0; i < revText.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(revText.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("*************************************\n");
        System.out.println("Below the reversed text is reversed again to normal:\n"
                         + "***************************************************");
        ArrayList<String> normalText = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < revText.size(); i++) {
            reverse(revText.get(i), normalText);            
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < normalText.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(normalText.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
    }

    public FileIOReverse(String x){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String oneLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            //calls the method to read a using bufferedReader

            while(oneLine!=null){
                contents = oneLine;
                oneLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                reverse(contents, revText);
            }

            // Must follow this order: 
            // 1)Close the BufferedReader 
            // 2) Close the FileReader
            bufferedReader.close();
            fileReader.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occured");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void reverse(String text, ArrayList<String> arraylist){
        String txt = "";
        for(int m = text.length()-1; m >= 0; m--){
            txt+= Character.toString(text.charAt(m)); 
        } 
        //store the for loop result into a var for reuse
        arraylist.add(txt);
   }
}
```